# View cart issue

Tags: php, product, display

All the other parts of my application are working but my users view cart is not working I do not know whether if it is about the indexing

I have tried using outer php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
     <title>View table</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs  /popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th scope="col">Item</th>
       <th scope="col">brand</th>
       <th scope="col">flavour/type</th>
       <th scope="col">quantity</th>
       <th scope="col">Number of units</th>
       <th scope="col">Number of packets</th>
       <th scope="col">price</th>
       <th scope="col">Cost</th>
       <th scope="col">Picture</th>
       <th scope="col">D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php
  require_once("config.php");
  error_reporting(0);
  $email_address=$_SESSION['email_address'];
  $sql="SELECT product_name  ,brand,flavour_type,quantity,number_of_units,price ,units,image_path
   FROM gokcen.product NATURAL JOIN gokcen.cart  
   WHERE cart.email_address=:email_addres";
   $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(':email_address',$email_address);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result=$stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach($result as $product)
   { 
   ?>        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $product['product_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['brand'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['flavour_type'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['quantity'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['number_of_units'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['units'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['price'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['price']* $prouct['units'];?></td>
        <td> <img src="pics/<?php echo $product['image_path'];?>" width="80" height="80"/></td>
        <td><a href="deletefromcart.php?item=<?echo   product['product_name'];?>"> delete <a></td> 
  </tr>
  <?php }?>
  </tbody>  
  </table>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >Buy</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

There are no results It does not give  any errors it shows the header part only and Im not sure about the indexing.

Comment: `var_dump($email_address)` gives what? Why have you disabled error reporting?

Answer (score 1):

there are several typos in your code.

- When I am right there should be another "s" at the end? `cart.email_address=:email_addres`
- There is a "d" missing at line `<?php echo $product['price']* $prouct['units'];?>`
- You also missed the "$" sign at this point as well as the "php" after the question mark: `<?echo   product['product_name'];?>`

You should set display_errors to On in your php.ini and comment out the error_reporting(0); for debugging purposes :)

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo email_addres email_address.

```
WHERE cart.email_address=:email_addres";

$stmt->bindParam(':email_address',$email_address);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys you are the best you rock my coding life It was the typos and also that 
I had not put a

```
session_start()
```

To initialize the value of $email_address on

```
$email_address=$_SESSION['email_address'];
```

All the best!